# Changing one whole column in csv file into sequential numbers in Python

Tags: python, csv

My csv file is set up like this:

```
1001,14074759.040,2998701.019,5392.016,wieley road row
1002,14074784.067,2998693.658,5390.647,wieley road row
1003,14074807.389,2998684.350,5389.724,wieley road row
1004,14074875.098,2998653.571,5387.673,wieley road row
1005,14074912.698,2998634.952,5385.717,wieley road row
```

I have thousands of entries like this and I want to change the 0th line into a sequential set of numbers starting from 1. So far I can display the line I want to change. I am having trouble with the editing part.

```js
import csv

with open('1234.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for lines in readCSV:
      print(lines[0
            ])
     for line in readCSV:
```

Can I have help with changing each line sequentially?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: it will be a csv file

Comment: Yes. what are you expecting it to look like? I am not sure I understand what you mean by *change the 0th line into a sequential set of numbers starting from 1*

Comment: makes sense to me, the first column should become a sequence starting from 1

Comment: So you need a header line?

Comment: i meant to say column sorry. i want the first deliminator of every row to be changed from the existing number to number 1, +1.

Comment: so 1001 will be 1, 1002 will be 2, so on

Comment: So you want a numerical index for each row right? You could use `enumerate` for that and drop the first item in the row.

Comment: a header line will conflict with the import process when i use this file on my trimble unit. ill see what i can do with enumerate.

Comment: I see. I was just trying to guess what you meant by *change the 0th line*.  `for i, lines in enumerate(readCSV)` should do what you want. And then as I said drop the first item in each row, so `row[1:]`

Comment: thank you for the lead. ill check back in when i get to the next step. i may be a while.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate` over the `csv.reader` object and start the enumeration from `1` as shown below.

```
import csv

with open('1234.csv', 'r') as fin, open('modified.csv', 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for idx, line in enumerate(reader, 1):
        output = [idx] + line[1:]
        writer.writerow(output)
```

File then looks like this:

```
1,14074759.040,2998701.019,5392.016,wieley road row
2,14074784.067,2998693.658,5390.647,wieley road row
3,14074807.389,2998684.350,5389.724,wieley road row
4,14074875.098,2998653.571,5387.673,wieley road row
5,14074912.698,2998634.952,5385.717,wieley road row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas library to do it.
First import the csv to make a pandas dataframe, pandas automatically adds an index column. Increase the index by 1 to make it start from 1 instead of zero. Now save the dataframe back to a csv. 
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
df.index += 1
df.to_csv('outputfile.csv')
```

We have used `header = None` attribute to prevent the first line of csv from being treated as a title. The output is:

```
,0,1,2,3,4
1,1001,14074759.04,2998701.019,5392.016,wieley road row
2,1002,14074784.067,2998693.6580000003,5390.647,wieley road row
3,1003,14074807.389,2998684.35,5389.724,wieley road row
4,1004,14074875.098,2998653.5710000005,5387.673000000001,wieley road row
5,1005,14074912.697999999,2998634.952,5385.717,wieley road row
```

Now remove the first line to get your desired output.